# Trying to move a plugin element on Wordpress - pasting in container code deletes input class

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I have this plugin (Order Delivery Date Pro) element that is floating in between the products and the Cart Totals on the Woocommerce Cart page. I've tried every which way I can think of to get it included into the shipping area of the cart to make it less confusing for the end user. (picture below)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzLtT.png)

Here's the wrapper code that works when pasted in, but the input box from the date selector disappears and is no longer clickable, making the delivery calendar unusable.

How do I get this thing where it needs to be?

```
   <tr>
    <th>Choose Date</th>
     <td class="deliver-a">
      <p class="main-cont form-row form-row-wide validate-required" id="e_deliverydate_field" data-priority="">
       <label for="e_deliverydate" class="">Delivery Date<abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
        <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
         <input type="text" class="input-text hasDatepicker" name="e_deliverydate" id="e_deliverydate" placeholder="Choose a Date" value="" style="cursor:text !important;max-width:300px;" aria-describedby="Delivery Date">
        </span>
     </td>
   </tr>
```